# Iterate list of strings in mithril and create drop down

Tags: javascript, frameworks, dom-events, mithril.js

I tried searching a lot of internet but could not find answer to a simple question. I am very new to mithril (do not know why people chose mithril for project :( ). I want to iterate through a list of strings and use its value in drop down with a checkbox.

```
const DefaultListView = {
    view(ctrl, args) {
    const parentCtrl = args.parentCtrl;
    const attr = args.attr;
    const cssClass = args.cssClass;
    const filterOptions = ['Pending', 'Paid', 'Rejected'];
    // as of now, all are isMultipleSelection filter
    const selectedValue = 
    parentCtrl.filterModel.getSelectedFilterValue(attr);

    function isOptionSelected(value) {
      return selectedValue.indexOf(value) > -1;
    }

    return m('.filter-dialog__default-attr-listing', {
      class: cssClass
    }, [
      m('.attributes', {
        onscroll: () => {
          m.redraw(true);
        }
      }, [
        filterOptions.list.map(filter => [
          m('.dropdown-item', {
            onclick() {
              // Todo: Add click metrics.
              // To be done at time of backend integration.
              document.body.click();
            }
          }, [
            m('input.form-check-input', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              checked: isOptionSelected(filter)
            }),
            m('.dropdown-text', 'Pending')
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ]);
  }
};
```

Not sure. How to do it. This is what I have tried so far but no luck. Can someone help me this?

Answer (score 1):

At the beginning of the `view` function you define an array:

```
const filterOptions = ['Pending', 'Paid', 'Rejected'];
```

But later on in the view code where you perform the list iteration, `filterOptions` is expected to be an object with a `list` property:

```
filterOptions.list.map(filter =>
```

That should be `filterOptions.map(filter =>`.

There may be other issues with your code but it's impossible to tell without seeing the containing component which passes down the `args`. You might find it more helpful to ask the [Mithril chatroom](https://gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js), where myself and plenty of others are available to discuss & assist with tricky situations.